# Convert scanned PDF to Plain Text using Ghostscript

Tags: pdf, tesseract, ghostscript

I know there is a way to convert scannedPDF document to OCR'd PDF document using [Ghostscript](https://www.ghostscript.com/ocr.html#updated), using the below command:

```
> bin\gswin64c.exe -sDEVICE=pdfocr32 -o D:\OCR\outputOCRdPDF.pdf -r600 -dDownScaleFactor=3 InputScannedPDF.pdf
```

and it uses the [Tesseract](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract) open source to do that. As per the [available devices of GS for OCR](https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/current/News.htm), It converts to another PDF document, and not just simple text (whereas tesseract does it to plain text as well).

Looks like I am missing something related to usage. Please correct me here or provide your valuable suggestions to convert to simple text instead of PDF

Answer (score 0):

1. Convert pdf to tif (in cased o multipage document) or other image from (with ghostcript, [mupdf](https://mupdf.com/docs/manual-mutool-convert.html), or extract images from pdf (if pdf was created with scanner)
2. OCR images with tesseract.